# Why does GCC's stdlibc++ define WeaklyIncrementable iterator requires moveable and it's difference_type must be integral? What benefits do they give?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts, range-v3

While I'm trying to understand the ostream_joiner's std::ranges algorithm requirement concept failure fiasco, I found that GCC implementation of WeaklyIncrementable iterator looks somewhat different from the standard.

GCC 10.2 stdlibc++ "[iterator_concept.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00440_source.html)" defines weakly_incrementable also requires

- moveable
- __is_signed_integer_like<iter_difference_t<_Iter>>
  which seems to requires Iter::different_type is signed integral or can be "long long".

```
   template<typename _Tp> requires requires { typename _Tp::difference_type; }
     struct incrementable_traits<_Tp>
     { using difference_type = typename _Tp::difference_type; };
  
   template<typename _Tp>
     requires (!requires { typename _Tp::difference_type; }
               && requires(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
               {
                 requires (!is_void_v<remove_pointer_t<_Tp>>); // PR c++/78173
                 { __a - __b } -> integral;
               })
     struct incrementable_traits<_Tp>
     {
       using difference_type
         = make_signed_t<decltype(std::declval<_Tp>() - std::declval<_Tp>())>;
     };
   ...
   template<typename _Tp>
     using iter_difference_t = __detail::__iter_diff_t<remove_cvref_t<_Tp>>;
   ...
     using __max_diff_type = long long;
     ...
     template<typename _Tp>
       concept __is_signed_integer_like = signed_integral<_Tp>
         || same_as<_Tp, __max_diff_type>;
   ...
   /// Requirements on types that can be incremented with ++.
   template<typename _Iter>
     concept weakly_incrementable = default_initializable<_Iter>
       && movable<_Iter>
       && requires(_Iter __i)
       {
         typename iter_difference_t<_Iter>;
         requires __detail::__is_signed_integer_like<iter_difference_t<_Iter>>;
         { ++__i } -> same_as<_Iter&>;
         __i++;
       };
```

This seems more strict than [semiregular](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/semiregular) in the standard that requires only std::copyable.

Why? What benefits do they give?

Is it okey/possible/should to write ostream_joiner that satisfies WeaklyIncrementable iterator?

Comment: [Because the standard says so](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.winc). What, exactly, is the "fiasco"?

Comment: @T.C. Oh, indeed. There are both *exp::ranges::WeaklyIncrementable* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/WeaklyIncrementable and *std::weakly_incrementable* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable already. Anyway why did they replace with moveable and choose not to define "semiregular" ? About fiasco, *ostream_joiner* can not be used as out iterator with ranges algorithms. However, I now see that *ostream_iterator* now satisfies *std::default_initializable* requirement while *ostream_joiner* has not yet get added its default constructor.

Comment: @T.C. Is it okey to just add a default constructor into *ostream_joiner* to use with ranges' algorithms?